# Should I use async/await to run 3 operations at the same time?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, multitasking

I have a WCF service and a contract I rather not to change (although if it's necessary I will have to):

```
[OperationContract]
PackageDto GetPackage(int id);
```

and there is the Service:

```
public PackageDto GetPackage(int id)
{
    var foo1 = FooData.GetFoo1(id);
    var foo2 = FooData.GetFoo2(id);
    var foo3 = FooData.GetFoo3(id);

    var bar1 = FooLogic.CalculateBar(foo1, foo2, foo3);
    var bar2 = FooLogic.CalculateBar(foo1, foo2);

    return new PackageDto(){ Bar1 = bar1, Bar2 = bar2 };
}
```

I'm doing 3 independent data calls to get *foos*. I feel that I can run *foo* operations at the same time and await the all results. Then proceed as usual. I was thinking about **async/await**, but I'm not sure if this is the way to go. After all, we're talking about running stuff in parallel in the first place, not async. *Foo* methods are not "true" async methods, they do block the thread, so that's why I'm confused. Here's my idea:

```
public PackageDto GetPackage(int id)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        var foo1Task = Task.Run(() => FooData.GetFoo1(id));
        var foo2Task = Task.Run(() => FooData.GetFoo2(id));
        var foo3Task = Task.Run(() => FooData.GetFoo3(id));
        tasks.Add(foo1Task);
        tasks.Add(foo2Task);
        tasks.Add(foo3Task);
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        var bar1 = FooLogic.CalculateBar(foo1Task.Result, foo2Task.Result, foo3Task.Result);
        var bar2 = FooLogic.CalculateBar(foo1Task.Result, foo2Task.Result);

        return new PackageDto(){ Bar1 = bar1, Bar2 = bar2 };
    }).Result;
}
```

**What would you do?**

Comment: It depends on the nature of the call to `GetFoo`. If `FooData.GetFoo1..3` are all IO bound then there signature can be converted to an async one returning `Task` or `Task<T>`. If they're all CPU bound then you can use and concurrent method such as `Parallel.Foreach`. Either way wrapping things in `Task.Run` and using the blocking call `.Result` are never a the right choice.

Comment: Your general pattern looks ok, but I would turn `GetPackage` in to an actual `Task<PackageDto>`, and mark it as `async`.  Then you don't need your outer `Task.Run`, and you can just `await` it.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Task.WaitAll when I needed to run things in parallel:

```
Task foo1Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FooData.GetFoo1(id));
Task foo2Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FooData.GetFoo2(id));
Task foo3Task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FooData.GetFoo3(id));
Task.WaitAll(foo1Task, foo2Task, foo3Task);
```

Comment: `WaitAll` is a blocking call that can lead to deadlock and the three tasks you defined do not represent the inner work executing since they've been started with `Task.Factory`. Read up on the difference between `StartNew` and `Task.Run`.

Comment: He is looking for run 3 tasks in parallel and wait for them to be completed, so don't see the issue there...